# Take only elements from array that satisfy condition from its diff in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, diff

I am trying to write a function that takes as input an array, compute the diff of the array, and take only the values from the array where the index matches the index of diff(array) meeting a certain condition (diff values in the range [low_thresh, high_thresh]).

Here the code that I wrote in Python using numpy:

```
def get_rid_jumps(trace, low_tresh, high_thresh):
    trace_diff = np.pad(np.diff(trace), 1)
    trace_diff = trace_diff[1:]
    trace_out_jumps = trace[trace_diff < high_thresh and trace_diff > low_tresh]
    return  trace_out_jumps
```

But I do receive the error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The and doesn't do an element-wise comparison. For that, you need https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html

```
trace_out_jumps = trace[np.logical_and(trace_diff < high_thresh, trace_diff > low_tresh)]
```

But for this to work, you'll also need to convert trace to an array (as compared to the list you gave in your comments)

Comment: I tried that but I receive the same error

Comment: Can you provide some example inputs?

Comment: a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: perhaps `trace_out_jumps = trace[np.logical_and(trace_diff < high_thresh, trace_diff > low_tresh)]`?

Comment: I also tried that, and it does not work either...

Comment: I made a typo in the original answer, it's been fixed

Comment: you could also write `trace_out_jumps = trace[(trace_diff < high_thresh) & (trace_diff > low_tresh)]` since the python operator for bitwise AND is overloaded for elementwise AND in numpy